# extracting digits using recursion in python

Tags: recursion

```
def getdigits(n):
    if n<10:
        return [n]
    else:
        return [getdigits(n/10)]+[n%10]
```

But for 124 :

**Expected Output** : [1, 2, 4]
**Actual Output** :[[[1], 2], 4]

As far as I understand

- getdigits(124) = [getdigits(12)] + [4]
- getdigits(12) = [getdigits(1)] + [2]
- get digits(1) = [1]

Therefore,

- getdigits(124) = [1] + [2] + [4] = [1, 2, 4]

I figure there's something wrong in the second part of it as I can't see anything wrong with the condition. Any suggestions in this regard will be appreciated

Comment: `getdigits` returns a list and therefore `[getdigits()]` will have a list nested inside a list

Comment: Here is a short way to do roughly what it looks like you're trying to do. ``list(str(n))``

Answer (score 3):

Just need to remove the extra brackets:

```
def getdigits(n):
    if n<10:
        return [n]
    else:
        return getdigits(n/10) + [n%10]
```